# Lazy evaluation problem

Tags: clojure

I've a code like this. I can run this in repl but can't from command line.
I guess i've a lazy evaluation problem.

```
; items.clj

(def items (ref []))

(defn init-items []
  (map
    #(dosync
       (alter items conj %))
    ["foo" "bar" "baz" ] ))

(init-items)
(println (first @items))
```

```
$ java -jar clojure.jar items.clj
$ nil
```

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it!

[solution](http://ideone.com/CSrBU)

Clojure is not motivated to run the `map` function in `init-items` because there's no result returned. I wrapped that into a `doall` to force execution, and presto.

Comment: Actually `dorun` is better suited to this case (`doall` holds onto the head of the seq it wraps and returns it, whereas `dorun` discards it step by step and finally returns `nil` -- thus it's better suited to side-effecty code).

Comment: @Michal: You're absolutely correct, of course. I've dabbled a bit with Clojure but never reached high proficiency, and now, sadly, even that's starting to rust. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Actually doseq is better suited for side-effects. dorun is so ugly.

Comment: @kotarak: Good point. I was under the impression `doseq` was lazy but looking at the API it seems I was mistaken.

Comment: @Carl: there is the magic hint: *do*seq. ;) "do" in front normally means non-laziness.

Answer (score 4):

Some alternatives:

If you just want to add a bunch of items to a collection held in a Ref, starting one transaction per item and `conj`ing them separately is a bit wasteful. Instead, you could do

```
(defn init-items []
  (dosync (alter items into ["foo" "bar" "baz"])))
```

If you do have some reason to do it in a one-item-per-step fashion, I think the most idiomatic and convenient approach would currently be to use `doseq`:

```
(defn init-items []
  (doseq [item ["foo" "bar" "baz"]]
    (dosync (alter items conj item))))
```

(Or you could move wrap the entire `doseq` in a `dosync` and not use `dosync` in the `doseq`'s body.)